# Visual Studio doesn't find my references and they are already here

Tags: c#, reference, package, nuget

I'm coding a C# application. When I compile my code, I have hundreds of errors about some missing references and packages that I installed. Visual Studio indicate that it doesn't find them, but when I see the NuGet packages, they are all there!

This problem occurs after synchronising the project from git.

[image]

Comment: More than likely your solution is referencing a library that is not supported by your version of .NET, C# or vs. Try opening Nuget and searching for those references and seeing if there are updates you need to download.

Comment: all these references are Updates and they used to work before i synchronise the project from Git !

Comment: Try a project clean?

Comment: i wanted to let this solution as the last one ^^ but i think this is what i'm going to do now! uninstall all the package and install it again :'(

Comment: Can you post the content of your project file, as you see it from e.g. Notepad?

Comment: the project clean was useful, i was able to fix my errors
Thanks anyway for your comment ^^